# Disadvantage of two-hand weapon + shield in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a warrior in WOW, and I have an ability that allows me to wield both a two hand weapon, AND a shield. Is there any disadvantage to having the shield equipped as well?

Comment: Which spec are you playing? I don't think Titan Grip is available to protection warriors.

Comment: I'm playing fury..

Comment: You are playing fury, bc you have Titan's grip. Don't bother with the shield, you don't get the added bonuses from blocking. You're also missing out on TONS of dog by not equiping that second 2H.  **tl,dr; No bonus from shield, loss of DPs from no 2h**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Titan's Grip ability, which is gained at level 38 and allows one to wield two-handed weapons as if they are one-handed, is only available to fury-specced warriors.

When you use a shield as a fury warrior with Titan's Grip, you've essentially stumped your ability to deal maximum damage with your available gear, as a shield is supposed to provide protection, not to increase damage (or it increases little damage compared to a weapon, which has a weapon damage stat that shields don't have). The weapon damage stat (this includes the min-max damage figures combined with the weapon speed) provides the basis for the majority of damage you dish out as a melee DPS; a shield negates that property/advantage completely.

A fury warrior has no access to the immense arsenal of abilities that utilize the shield that a protection warrior has (with the exception of shield wall and spell reflection, which are available to all specs I believe). Therefore equipping a shield actually handicaps the fury warrior. The meagre amount of blocking and armor gained from the shield makes little improvement to his defensive capabilities. On the other hand, duel-wielding two two-handers allow the fury warrior full access to all the damaging abilities that take advantage of duel-wielding, that are otherwise unavailable or underutilized.

Part of learning to play WoW is to recognize your role in a team. When you are a DPS (someone whose role is to deal damage), you want to maximize your ability to perform this role with whatever resources are available to you. A shield is not such a resource you want to use. Use another two-hander instead in your shield slot.

Comment: This barely answers the question itself.

Comment: @FEichinger I've modified the answer slightly to emphasize on the difference between a shield and a weapon in general. The role of a DPS is also important here. If you have anything more constructive to add, please do go ahead and let me know.

Comment: I said "barely" because, while it did address it in context, it went on a tangent about how "You're not supposed to do that" - rather than giving a straight-up answer. ;)

Comment: although this is a great answer on its own it doesn't answer the question in topic. He was asking for advantage/disadvantages of using the shield. An possible advantage might be that he has more blocking capabilities while still having a decent amount of damage.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I can't say I agree with you on 'still having a decent amount of damage'. It's really an opinion in this case. Quite a few of the fury abilities take advantage of duel-wielding, such as raging blow and wild strike (as well as the loss of white damage from the offhand weapon). Besides, advantages/disavantages compared to what? I believe I have given a general account of what happens when one forgoes duelwield for a shield. If the OP wants more information, he's more than welcome to ask.

Comment: The only reason you'd ever want to use a shield as fury is to hit shield wall to stay alive from some event that's going to cause you to take a lot of damage.

Comment: considering that shieldwall could be used during a fight as a fury warrior, my mind is blown at the moment, and the stupid thing is that it is even possible... 40% reduced damage for the duration, if you are in the middle of a stay alive phase where very little damage is going out onto the boss, this would be insane, and im fairly certain it is allowed for players to change weapons during fights, so switch to shield on the heavy damage phase and then switch back to your 2 hander during the dps phase

Comment: @Ravekner That's what macros are for.

Comment: @Ravekner I have saved the day many times throughout the years while playing a dps warrior where I would tank the last 12 seconds or so of a fight (or at least draw it out that long) when the tank died right at the end. Also, it was useful on Algalon and Ultraxion mechanics (1-2 people had to eat a high damage ability every minute or so).

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage of using a shield as a Fury Warrior is that you are going to be significantly reducing your damage output, for a very small reduction in damage taken.

The shield will give you more armour, so you will take slightly less damage per hit.
However the fights will take longer, because you are dealing less damage, so you will end up getting hit more, and probably take more damage overall. The second 2-hander also likely has more raw stats then the shield, so you will probably have more HP, etc with the second weapon.

Even when you are soloing, I would say you are almost always better off with a second weapon as a Fury Warrior.